# Jquery to expand and collapse div on clicking a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Html looks like

```
<h3><a href="#" title="story title">Story Title</a>
    <img class="expandstory" src="/images/plus.png" /></h3>
<div class="description">Short description about the story</div>

<h3><a href="#" title="story title">Story Title</a>
    <img class="expandstory" src="/images/plus.png" /></h3>
<div class="description">Short description about the story</div>
```

My jquery looks like

```
$('.description').hide();
$('.description:first').show();
$('.expandstory:first').attr('src','/images/minus.png');
$('.expandstory:first').addClass('collapsestory');
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
   if($(this).attr('class')=='expandstory') {
       $(".description").slideUp(500);
       $(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500);
       $(this).attr('src','/images/minus.png');
       $(this).addClass('collapsestory');
       $(this).removeClass('expandstory');
   }
   else {
       $(".description").slideUp(500);
       $(this).attr('src','/images/plus.png');
       $(this).addClass('expandstory');
       $(this).removeClass('collapsestory');
   }
});
```

I am making a simple thing more complex and more over this is not working when I expand/collapse the div multiple times.

I cannot change the HTML file. Please provide me good solution in jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net). Also, define *'not working'*

Comment: Its jsFiddle.net i guess.. :/

Comment: Whoops.. I was rushing.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<h3><a href="#" title="story title">Story Title</a>
    <img class="expandstory" src="/images/plus.png" /></h3>
<div class="description hide">Short description about the story</div>

<h3><a href="#" title="story title">Story Title</a>
    <img class="expandstory" src="/images/plus.png" /></h3>
<div class="description hide">Short description about the story</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.show
{
display:block;
}
.hide
{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.expandstory').click(function(){       
    $(this).parent().next('.description').toggleClass('show hide');    
});
```

Something like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/XqauU/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you mean when you say it's 'not working'. But you mention that it stops working when you expand/collapse `<div>`s multiple times, which leads me to believe you have animation queue issues, which can be solved using [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Try this:

```
$('.description').hide();
$('.description:first').show();
$('.expandstory:first').attr('src','/images/minus.png');
$('.expandstory:first').addClass('collapsestory');
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
   if($(this).attr('class')=='expandstory') {
       $(".description").stop(true,false).slideUp(500); //Here..
       $(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').stop(true,false).slideToggle(500); //Here..
       $(this).attr('src','/images/minus.png');
       $(this).addClass('collapsestory');
       $(this).removeClass('expandstory');
   }
   else {
       $(".description").stop(true,false).slideUp(500); //And here..
       $(this).attr('src','/images/plus.png');
       $(this).addClass('expandstory');
       $(this).removeClass('collapsestory');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('img.expandstory').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $div = $this.parent().next();

    $('img.expandstory').not($this).prop('src', '/images/plus.png');
    $('div.description').not($div).slideUp(500);

    $this.prop('src', ( $div.is(':visible') ? '/images/plus.png' : '/images/minus.png' ));
    $div.slideToggle();

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x36aH/14/)

**Note:** In the fiddle I've modified the `alt` property of the `image` just so that you can see that it changing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe he is looking for something like :

```
$('h3').next('.description').hide();
$('h3').first().next('.description').show();
$('h3').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass('.expandstory');
    $('.description').stop().slideUp(500);
    $(this).next('.description').stop().slideDown(500);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSRRn/)